# Work with DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have `DataTable`, where one of columns is `DataStart, typeof(DateTime)`.
I try add one more column, where I calculate some date.
Like that:

```
DataColumn Deadline = table.Columns.Add("Deadline", typeof(DateTime));
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  row["Deadline"] = DataTime.Now.AddDays(10) - (DateTime)(row["DateStart"]);
}
```

But I take some error when run application:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <13.10:32:02.3571743> in Deadline
>   Column.  Expected type is DateTime.

How i must fix it?

Comment: Not to sound rude but _how to fix it_ is outlined very clearly in the error message... make sure you read those.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Yes, I read it. And I read documentation. And read google. But in end I can't fix it, so answer SO.

Answer (score 2):

If you add or subtract two datetimes the result is a `TimeSpan` which is the span between both. You want to subtract 10 days from the `DateStart`-time, don't you? Use `DateTime.TimeOfDay`:

```
row["Deadline"] = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10) + row.Field<DateTime>("DateStart").TimeOfDay;
```

The result of `DateTime` + `TimeSpan` is a `DateTime`. Note that i've also used `DateTime.Today.AddDays(10)` instead of `DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)` to truncate the time portion.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the following:

```
row["Deadline"] = DataTime.Now.AddDays(10) - (DateTime)(row["DateStart"]);
```

To:

```
row["Deadline"] = ((DateTime)(row["DateStart"])).AddDays(10);
```

This will create a new date, 10 days ahead of your `DateStart` value.  Currently you're trying to set the `Deadline` `DateTime` value using a `TimeSpan` which is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) - (DateTime)(row["DateStart"])` returns `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime`.

If you want to keep *time interval* on `DeadLine` column, you might want to change it's type like;

```
DataColumn Deadline = table.Columns.Add("Deadline", typeof(TimeSpan));
```

If you want to `10` days on that `DateStart`'s time part, you can use it's [`TimeOfDay` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday) like;

```
row["Deadline"] = DataTime.Today.AddDays(10) + (DateTime)(row["DateStart"]).TimeOfDay;
```